# How to retrieve a segmented List of Containers using the new Java v12 SDK for Azure Blob Storage?

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, cloud-storage, azure-java-sdk

I see that the .NET examples have a **ListContainersSegmented** API call.

The Java SDK documentation specifies a **listBlobContainers** call but there is no mention about when it hits the limit of containers it will return per call. Is there a different way to obtain the *NextMarker* or *ContinuationToken* for this call?

Comment: Do you have any other concerns?

Comment: @JimXu This is good. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When we use the method `listBlobContainers` to list containers, It will paginate if its number is greater than 5000. We also can use `ListBlobContainersOptions` to define per page size. For more details, please refer to [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/java/api/com.azure.storage.blob.blobserviceclient.listblobcontainers?view=azure-java-stable#com_azure_storage_blob_BlobServiceClient_listBlobContainers_com_azure_storage_blob_models_ListBlobContainersOptions_java_time_Duration_) and [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/list-containers2)

for example

```
String endpoint = String.format(Locale.ROOT, "https://%s.blob.core.windows.net", accountName);
        StorageSharedKeyCredential credential = new StorageSharedKeyCredential(accountName, accountKey);
        BlobServiceClient blobServiceClient = new BlobServiceClientBuilder()
                .endpoint(endpoint)
                .credential(credential)
                .buildClient();
        ListBlobContainersOptions options = new ListBlobContainersOptions();
        options.setMaxResultsPerPage(5);
        PagedIterable<BlobContainerItem> pagedIterableResponse= blobServiceClient.listBlobContainers(options, null);
        Iterator<PagedResponse<BlobContainerItem>> ite = pagedIterableResponse.iterableByPage().iterator();
        int i =1;
        while(ite.hasNext()){
            PagedResponse<BlobContainerItem> items= ite.next();
            System.out.println("The containers in the page "+i);
            i++;
            for (BlobContainerItem item: items.getValue()
                 ) {

                   System.out.println("\t"+item.getName());
            }

        }
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

We can use the following method to get the continuation token

```
        List<BlobItem> allBlobs = new ArrayList<>();
        String continuationToken;
        ListBlobsOptions options = new ListBlobsOptions().setMaxResultsPerPage(5);
        Iterator<PagedResponse<BlobItem>> response = containerClient.listBlobs(options, Duration.ofSeconds(30)).iterableByPage().iterator();
        do {
            PagedResponse<BlobItem> pagedResponse = response.next();
            List<BlobItem> blobs = pagedResponse.getValue();
            continuationToken = pagedResponse.getContinuationToken();
            blobs.forEach(b -> System.out.println(b.getName()));
            allBlobs.addAll(blobs);
        } while (continuationToken != null);
```